# SqlQuery: how to capture results of sp_columns?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I need to get the structure of the table, created a database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I found to get the structure need the command

```
exec sp_columns TableName
```

Focusing on [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql) created some code:

```
public class ResultSchema
{
    public object TABLE_QUALIFIER { get; set; }
    public object TABLE_OWNER { get; set; }
    public object TABLE_NAME { get; set; }
    public object COLUMN_NAME { get; set; }
    public object DATA_TYPE { get; set; }
    public object TYPE_NAME { get; set; }
    public object PRECISION { get; set; }
    public object LENGTH { get; set; }
    public object SCALE { get; set; }
    public object RADIX { get; set; }
    public object NULLABLE { get; set; }
    public object REMARKS { get; set; }
    public object COLUMN_DEF { get; set; }
    public object SQL_DATA_TYPE { get; set; }
    public object SQL_DATETIME_SUB { get; set; }
    public object CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH { get; set; }
    public object ORDINAL_POSITION { get; set; }
    public object IS_NULLABLE { get; set; }
    public object SS_DATA_TYPE { get; set; }
}

SampleContext context = new SampleContext(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ExampleDB1;Trusted_Connection=true");

var structure = context.Database.SqlQuery<ResultSchema>("EXEC sp_columns Tovars").ToList();
```

but as a result, I only get null values, what am I doing wrong? How to get the table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF can't materialize to `object`, it always needs a specific data type. In other words, the data types of `ResultSchema`'s properties should match those of the columns returned by the stored procedure:

```
public class ResultSchema
{
    public string TABLE_QUALIFIER { get; set; }
    public string TABLE_OWNER { get; set; }
    public string TABLE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string COLUMN_NAME { get; set; }
    public Int16 DATA_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string TYPE_NAME { get; set; }
    public int PRECISION { get; set; }
    public int LENGTH { get; set; }
    public Int16? SCALE { get; set; }
    public Int16? RADIX { get; set; }
    public Int16 NULLABLE { get; set; }
    public string REMARKS { get; set; }
    public string COLUMN_DEF { get; set; }
    public Int16 SQL_DATA_TYPE { get; set; }
    public Int16? SQL_DATETIME_SUB { get; set; }
    public int? CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH { get; set; }
    public int ORDINAL_POSITION { get; set; }
    public string IS_NULLABLE { get; set; }
    public byte? SS_DATA_TYPE { get; set; }
}
```